# How to repair bend in pewter goblet stem

Tags: metalworking

I have a number of pewter goblets (by Royal Selangor) in the form of various characters from Lord of the Rings.

Unfortunately, Gimli recently fell from a first-floor (US - second-floor) window into a hedge. The landing was soft enough that the pewter hasn't dented or deformed; but it has gained a roughly 10-degree bend.

[This is what the goblet should look like](https://uk.royalselangor.com/gimli-goblet-the-lord-of-the-rings.html?___store=uk) (Royal Selangor's site). Attached are pictures of how the goblet is now. I believe the bend is most likely in the stem (which is styled as Gimli's beard), possibly near the bottom around where I have taken the close-up photo, since the metal seems perhaps slightly to have flattened there.

[image: Bent goblet, side view][image: Close up of possible bend location]

I would like to bend the goblet back into shape. Is this something I'm likely to be able to do myself, and if so, how would I go about it? I don't have any specialist metalworking tools, just a general purpose DIY toolkit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very likely it can just be straightened with no additional treatment. Tin strain hardens ( cold works) very slowly compared to most metals and will stress relieve at room temperature.  According to old references "pewter" ( a k a - Britannia metal ) is not pure tin but contains 7% antimony and 2% copper. But because this is apparently a newer product, one is not sure what the composition is ( I have seen zinc and aluminum novelties called "pewter"). I suggest straightening it, if it cracks it is unlikely to be tin/pewter.

Comment: Ok, that sounds promising. How though? I mean, I don't suppose I'd be able just to flex it with my bare hands...

Comment: Pewter is surprisingly soft. I've bent the pewter handle on a cake slice (only slightly thinner than this stem appears) by trying to cut pastry with it. The difficulty will be getting a good grip either side of the bend. However pewter is harder than tin, and harder metals tend to be more brittle.

Comment: Ok, then - I'll (with some trepidation) give it a go and report back. Otherwise, I shall try my friendly local jewellers.

Comment: The crackling noise is really quite off-putting, but that seems to have worked. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't mention , tin is unusual , it makes squeaks and other sounds when it is deformed .